# Plant (lamp) identification

Tags: botany

I recently came across this lamp part and wanted to get a lamp shade in the shape of the matching blossom.

Does someone recognize the leaves?

[image: brass flower lamp part]

Comment: Flower bracts are wrong, but Thistle springs to mind. May not represent a real plant after all.

Answer (score -1):

It looks to be a poppy, possibly the breadseed poppy

The flower has 4 perianth segments remaining after anthesis,matching the breadseed poppy where the sepals are abscised during anthesis leaving 4 petals.
the leaves are toothed, matching *papaver somniferum *

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. Answers on this site are typically upvoted if they contain information that supports the answer - in this case you could supply some information about the poppy, possibly including photos (proper attribution of photo source required) and why you think it is a match for the item in the photo from the question.

Comment: Different people see different flowers, interesting. Although the leaves are consistent with Poppies (good guess), the head is definitely not. At no stage does the poppy resemble that "flower". I initially thought "Tulip, but the leaves are wrong" (your guess is better than mine), bob1 thought "Thistle" (a v. good guess). The flower is either a stylized version of a flower m unfamiliar with or one that is non-existent. (I've seen **a lot** of flowers, as I used to travel the continent to do wildflower and garden flower photography, the latter containing plenty of non-natives)

Comment: I know, I'm a the very definition of a stickler for fine detail. Also, guesses are not acceptable in answers on scientific sites like this one. We require sources for answers.[Morphology, Taxonomy, Anatomy, and Palynology of the Opium Poppy (Papaver somniferum L.) Cultivation in Northern Thailand](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC10255261/).  Note figs. 3 and 4

Comment: It may be a general rendition of a poppy rather than a specific poppy.                                               Tulips have perianths with six tepals and thistles have capitulums

Comment: Poppies have 2 sepals  (which fall off before the flower opens) and 4-6 petals, and they don't look like those. We can't identify it; it probably doesn't exist. The good news is you can make a lampshade however you want! :)

Comment: The 4 petals of a poppy match quite well with the lampshade

Comment: I will admit to being wrong if somebody shows me a better match

Comment: Why don't you post a photograph of a poppy blossom (any poppy blossom, not necessarily breadseed poppy) with *pointed petals*? That would help with your answer's credibility.

Comment: What do you mean by pointed petal